# download file from url in assembly language in osx

Tags: macos, assembly, download

For downloading a file using bash or shell I call execve syscall to run curl command

```
  int execve(char *fname, char **argp, char **envp);
```

But the problem is i want download file with my own code not with curl or another.

I studied curl source code but it is too large and hard to figure out.

Is there any way to download a file within my program without using another programs in mac osx with intel 64.

Any clue for solving this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Download from where?

If assume you want to download from a WWW, it is pretty simple task:

1. Using sys_socketcall (eax=102) create a socket, then connect to the desired URL, then send a HTTP command:

   ```
   http_request db "GET /file_url HTTP/1.1", 13, 10, 13, 10
   ```
2. Read the socket by lines until you receive double CRLF (like in the request line). The first of the received lines contains the HTTP status code. If this line starts with '200 OK', then everything is OK. (Well, **[there are other status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)**, some of them are not exactly errors, but for simplest case, only '200 OK' matters.) The following received lines, before the double CRLF are so called server headers and can contain some useful information, but for details, read **[HTTP specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)**.
3. After the double CRLF, and if the status is '200 OK', the requested file is transmitted. Simply read the socket and store the file until the server close the socket.

For the other Internet protocols (such as FTP), the pattern is generally the same, only the commands are different.

Notice: The proper errors processing can be much harder than this simple algorithm.

Reference: **[LSCR project](http://lscr.sourceforge.net/)** contains very useful assembly-centric documentation on Linux system calls and examples.